# Combining data from different columns into a line graph with SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Hi I am new to SSRS and I am trying to create a line graph from the following dataset that has a single line and I am confused with how to achieve this simple task.

```
column1|column2|column3
1,11,35
```

If I try and add column 1-3 as values it will show nothing because it is trying to do a separate line per column.

I have tried making a temp table in sql and reformatting it as follows:

```
values
1
11
35
```

This works however this causes me to lose the axis names for each value.

How can I achieve a single line in my line graph as well as keeping the axis names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in that you need separate rows (i.e. pivoting your data) to meet your chart requirements.

You can need to add another column to your new Dataset to have group names, too:

[image]

Just example names, obviously.

In your chart, add the Series and Category as required:

[image]

Now you have labels on the axis:

[image]